# WPF DataTemplate for Collection

Tags: wpf, binding, collections, datatemplate

I must now hang my head, for I have scoured the Google for hours and still have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Controllers}">
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Port}" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

What I'm *trying* to do is to display an arbitrary number of controller objects in this list. "Controllers" is just an alias for "List<Controller>". "Port" is a property of each "Controller" object, but of course that's not showing up on the list. Items are being correctly added to the collection the list is based on (the collection is actually stored as the Content property of the ContentControl that is displaying this collection of objects), but no item in the collection itself is being displayed.

I thought at first that it might be an update issue--that the collection was being correctly displayed in its initial, empty state, but that isn't the case; if I start with the collection already populated, I still get no items.

Help me, Obi Wan. :(

Comment: What do you mean "Controllers" is just an alias for "List<Controller>"? Did you create a class where Controllers inherits from List<Controller>?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I mean. Wasn't sure what the best way to express that was. Sorry. :)

Comment: Found out that I needed to bind this whole thing to an observable collection in order to make it update automatically when items get added and removed, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind something to the `ListBox`. That something is just `{Binding}`, which refers to the instance of the `DataTemplate`s `DataType` that is passed in at run-time.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Controllers}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Port}" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that setting the ItemsSource to binding doesn't work. I've tried it before, actually (and of course I just tried it again after reading your comment!), but the box stays perfectly blank regardless. Could there be something else that I'm doing wrong that prevents this from having the desired effect?

Comment: Ok, Christoffer's answer is correct: the only catch is that, without some kind of update in the mix, it doesn't display new items on the list. :)